# How to validate whether correspondent entry in other table exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

How do i validate a column in one table against entries in other tables?

The code I used to validate that the entry for column ":product_id" of table "Preperiod" exists in the column "id" of table "Product" is

```
validate :product_id_exists
def product_id_exists
 if Product.find_by_id(:product_id)==nil
   errors.add(:base, "Product must be defined")
 end
end
```

But now I get the error even when the product_id is right. What did I do wrong?

I use ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.9

Comment: What language and / or database system??? In general, this sounds like a classic case for a foreign key relationship between two tables in a relational database system...

Comment: I've added the rails tag because it looks like a Rails question. Is that correct?

Comment: @marc_c I use ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.9

Comment: why the colon `:` in `Product.find_by_id(:product)`? Is it a typo error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.find_by_id('here you should specify value of id field ... ') == nil
```

so you your code should look like:

```
Product.find_by_id(product_id) == nil
```

or:

```
Product.find_by_id(self.product_id) == nil
```

or:

```
Product.find_by_id(self[:product_id]) == nil
```

Comment: when you are writing code like this, it's a best practice to use `.nil?` or in the other case `.present?` methods: `Product.find_by_id(product_id).nil?`